# Work Items were lost during TFS upgrade

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012, tfs-2013

Last week I upgraded our TFS 2012 Server to TFS 2013.  I read the MSDN documentation first and I also followed the documentation as I performed the upgrade.  Everything seemed to go ok.

After the upgrade I ended up with 7 or so Team Projects that the wizard couldn't configure, for whatever reason, and needed manual configuration.

I noticed this week that ALL of the work items under one of my Team Projects are missing.  Gone.  Like even if I select Team|Go To Work Item and enter in a known Work Item Id, I receive an error that the item is either missing or I do not have permission to view it.  I'm an Administrator on the TFS server and I'm the TFS Admin, so I highly doubt permissions are the issue.

I remoted into the server and launched SSMS to explore the raw data.  I know for a fact Work Item 450 is missing (it's the only Id I remember at this point).  I selected the TOP 1000 from WorkItemsAre, which seems to be the table that holds the Work Items (?).  There is a gap in the Ids, I see 1-448, then the numbering picks up again at 457.  So, somehow my Work Items appear to have been deleted.  I stopped there, I assume there are more gaps since I'm missing more than 9 items.

Now I haven't gone through every one of our Team Projects.  I've only touched 3 of them since the upgrade.  Thankfully the largest, most active Team Project, with the most work items/version history seems to be intact.  I'm not sure if any other Team Projects are missing their Work Items too.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Does anyone know if there's some "secret squirrel" way to recover these missing work items, or have they been hard deleted and are gone for good (other than looking through tape backups of the server).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd also like an answer. We are upgrading to TFS 2013 from 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I already migrated to TFS 2013 from TFS 2012.
The problem of manual configuring the project may occur when you have customized work item types in TFS Project Templates. Did you customize your project templates?

Although, I can hardly believe that work-items getting hard deleted from TFS. This issue may occur probably because of archiving during migration. The workitems that TFS upgrade wizard may not have "understood" during migration/upgrade, might be archived and moved to another table in database Tfs_DefaultCollection.

You may want to consider that. I am not sure if that may be the case, but this happened when we migrated from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 because we had many custom work items in TFS 2010. Hence we had to standardize templates before migration using powershell. But we lost some amount of history.
Hope that sparks some idea.